# How can I get the meta data of a Firebase node?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to know when the node was created, when it was last updated, etc.  That would be good information.

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't accepted my answer? A duplicate was just posted and I'd prefer to close it against this answer.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

There is no such metadata available in the Firebase Database. If you want this type of data, you'll have to add it to the nodes yourself. Using [server-side timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) for these will ensure they always have the right value.